# How to solve problema with Datatables

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am having a problem loading a list of records made in **DataTables** using **C#**, the problem is that loading the table gives me the following error

[image]

Once this happens I will review the error in the browser console, it shows me the following:

[image]

The following is the code in the controller with which the list of records is loaded

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtain tickets from the database and process them to be presented in the Datatable
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Json with the tickets available in the system</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMyTickets([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))]
        IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
    {
        using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
        {
            IQueryable<TicketsResult> query;               
            if (string.Equals(Session["tipo"].ToString(), "admin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                     string.Equals(Session["tipo"].ToString(), "mesa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                     string.Equals(Session["tipo"].ToString(), "coor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                query = TicketListModel.ConsultTicketListTech(Session["area"].ToString(),
                    Session["matricula"].ToString(), db);
            else
            {
                query = null;
            }

            var totalCount = query.Count();

            // Searching 
            if (requestModel.Search.Value != string.Empty)
            {
                var value = requestModel.Search.Value.Trim();
                query = query.Where(p => p.TicketFolio.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.TicketAplicant.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.TicketService.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.TicketStatus.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.TicketSubjet.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.TicketEmployee.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.Origin.Contains(value) ||
                                         p.SLALabel.Contains(value)
                );
            }

            var filteredCount = query.Count();

            // Sorting 
            var sortedColumns = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns();
            var orderByString = string.Empty;

            foreach (var column in sortedColumns)
            {
                orderByString += orderByString != string.Empty ? "," : "";
                orderByString += column.Data +
                                 (column.SortDirection == Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant ? " asc" : " desc");
            }

            query = query.OrderBy(orderByString == string.Empty ? "TicketFolio desc" : orderByString);

            // Paging 
            query = query.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);

            var data = query.Select(ticket => new
            {
                ticket.TicketId,
                ticket.TicketFolio,
                ticket.TicketAplicant,
                ticket.TicketService,
                ticket.TicketStatus,
                ticket.TicketSubjet,
                ticket.TicketEmployee,
                ticket.TicketSLAHourType,
                ticket.TicketSLAHours,
                ticket.Origin,
                ticket.SLALabel
            }).ToList();

            return Json(new DataTablesResponse(requestModel.Draw, data, filteredCount, totalCount));
        }
    }
```

The funny thing about this is that the error is displayed after it takes more than 30 seconds to load and this happens occasionally, it does not always come out, it is a table with approximately 6,000 records. What solution can you give me at least that the message I add at the beginning is not shown, I was thinking something like removing the exception while you can review it in more detail or what other solution can you give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't configured your application to log exceptions, your best bet is usually to open the Windows Event Viewer and look at the Application log.

You can filter the log to only show errors and critical. That usually helps.

HTTP 500 errors like the one you're getting often land here in the Event Viewer.

[image]

If you're able to debug your application, you can configure VS to break on all Exceptions by ensuring there's a check here on Common Language Runtime Exceptions in your Exception Settings window. Then just trigger the problem and VS will stop to tell you what's happening.

[image]

I'm assuming that you're just not able to debug the application, though.